# Why Visual Studio in C++ is not as intelligent as it's in C#?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I'm wokring on a homework in C++ in Visual Studio 2010, I've found that Visual Studio is not as wonderful as it is in C#. No intellisense , No code formating and stupid load of error messages which they might be gone togother if one error has been fixed.

Why that?

Comment: "stupid load of error messages which they might be gone togother if one error has been fixed" That is just one of the joys of programming in C++.  As for the other things, Visual Studio does provide IntelliSense, code colorization, formatting, and even limited in-IDE syntax checking ("squiggles") for C++; are you sure you haven't screwed up your Visual Studio settings?  If you create a new empty C++ project and add a .cpp file, do you get any IntelliSense?

Comment: With regard to code formatting, Tools > Options > Text Editor and make sure that C/C++ category has the same options you were used to in C# (which is right above).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Microsoft has not been putting much effort into its C++ tools since .NET appeared.  In a lot of ways, the current IDE is worse than Visual C++ 6.

Here is the Visual C++ team's blog entry about recent C++-related work and why there is no Intellisense for C++/CLI: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/03/10136696.aspx

Comment: Are you being nostalgic? Have you used VC 6 lately? I had to recently for an old project. VS 2010 is much better in every way for C++.

Comment: @Byron: Do you actually know how to use VC6? I've used it quite recently, and Kristopher is absolutely right: while VS 2010 is prettier, in terms of actual functionality, VC 5/6 was *clearly* superior.

Comment: @Kristopher Johnson: Actually this answer has convinced me more than that C++ is much complicated than C#. I think it's maybe a business reason more than complexity in languages

Comment: @Jack I don't think MS have set out to make C++ look bad. They clearly lost interest in native tools for a while when they were working mainly on .net. To some extent that's understandable because .net was/is a huge undertaking. Recently they have worked very hard on their C++ compiler with standards work and C++0x support. Maybe they haven't worked as hard on the IDE as they might. But C++ really is a challenge, mostly because of the burden of history.

Comment: I'd agree that there are sound business reasons for devoting more resources to C# development tools than to C++ development tools.  And Microsoft is not alone: I don't think there are _any_ good IDEs whose support for C++ comes close to their support for Java, Javascript, Python, Objective-C, or whatever.

Comment: This...really isn't true. Your opinion is that VS 2010 is not as good as VC++ 6. It's a somewhat widely-held opinion, and there's nothing wrong with that. But it isn't true to say that Microsoft has not put as much effort into C++ since .NET appeared. The IDE and compilers are handled by two *completely* different teams (actually, three: VB.NET is separate from C#). The problem is that C++ is a *much* more difficult language to parse than C#. That's why Intellisense support is comparatively worse, as well as refactoring and automatic formatting support lacking.

Answer (score 8):

C++ is a much much more complex language than C# which makes it very hard for a tool to parse and provide Intellisense feedback.

Comment: @Heandel how does C++ only parse once? C++ has to process the macros... Then process the templates... Then process the rest... Then expand the used templates and process that...

Comment: @David Heffernan: There is someone has downvoted on the question and all the answers and voted to close the question. I don't know but seems it's just for harming.

Comment: @Jack Sorry for assuming it was you.

Comment: I think "complex" is wrong word to describe it, but I agree that main problem here is not the IDE, but the language and library itself.

Comment: While I agree that C++ is a more complex language than most, if a compiler can parse it and generate code then an IDE can parse it to generate reasonable Intellisense suggestions.  Note that VS 2010 *does* have Intellisense for native C++ apps, but provides no Intellisense for managed C++/CLI apps.  I don't think that is because providing Intellisense is "very hard", but rather because they didn't have the resources or time to make it happen.

Comment: @Kristopher No intellisense for managed C++ is down to resources. You point about complexity misses the fact that C++ compilation is slow and Intellisense needs to be quick. It seems plausible to me that a more complex language would lead to a less functional Intellisense.

Comment: Why woukd parsing C++ for native code be that much different from parsing C++ for managed code?  VC6 did an adequate job of C++ parsing back in the mid 90's; I find it hard to believe that similar functionality is beyond the computational ability of today's machines.

Comment: BTW, here is the Visual C++ team's blog entry about why Intellisense is missing for C++/CLI: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/03/03/10136696.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Current versions of VC++ do have Intellisense, but it doesn't work particularly well. If you need to use it much, you might want to consider getting a copy of [Visual Assist X](http://www.wholetomato.com/). It improves Intellisense, syntax highlighting, and makes VS better in general.

Comment: Ya, I do know that there are third party solution, but I wonder why it's without these third party tools still stupid to this level comparing with C# one.

Comment: @Jack OK, I can see that now. Sorry to cast aspersions.

Comment: @Jack: It's impossible to say why with any real certainty. Unlike David Heffernan, I think it probably is intentional. My own guess is that Microsoft would have quit selling most native tools long ago if they thought they could get away with it. As-is, they do their best to steer people toward .NET, and keep native tools *just* good enough to keep third parties from developing better tools. They *have* improved their native tools, but I think only when (for example) Qt scared them into it.

Comment: Consider that the tools are still used *extensively* in-house. There's obviously no way to validate your claim that MS would prefer to stop *selling* native C++ tools. But they certainly have no interest in ceasing to improve them altogether. They're used in almost every division within Microsoft, from applications to system software, to develop native programs. It has nothing to do with Qt, and I'm not much for conspiracy theories like this one.

Comment: @Cody: They use the *compiler* in-house a lot, and there's no question they've improved the compiler a lot. There's a lot less certainty about how much they use the IDE for C++ development in-house -- and it not only hasn't been improved, but has had useful, important features *removed*.

Comment: VS 2010 still provides no Intellisense for managed C++/CLI projects.  It is only available for native C++ projects.

Answer (score 1):

c++ is a much more complex language to handle well from an IDE. Macros make intellisense somewhat more difficult. They also allow you to create lots of errors with each change :)